# What is AirAsia's "embargo period" they mention but seldom actually define?

Tags: terminology, airasia

I was just looking at [a list of deals on AirAsia's site](https://www.airasia.com/au/en/promotion.page) and one of its "travel notes" says

> Fares are not available during embargo period

So I'm assuming this is a specific date range. But they don't seem to tell us what that date range is.

When I google for it, I find they've been mentioning this embargo period for at least a few years, and I can find some people asking what it means, but I can't find an official definition.

I can find some sporadic bits and pieces, not official, mentioning festive times and other stuff. This makes it seem like it's not just one date range, even though they always use "embargo period" in the singular.

Where can I find a straight and detailed answer, preferably on AirAsia's site somewhere telling us exactly what this period, or periods, is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a convoluted way of saying "**these fares may not be available during dates that we decide**".  For example, one of the fares is listed as being valid "6 August 2018 - 31 January 2019", but if you click through to December you'll see that prices double around Christmas.  This is because the discounted fares are either no longer available or (more likely) were never available in the first place, hence "embargo".

[image]

And no, you can't find the periods anywhere, because Air Asia reserves the right to change them without notice.